# What is the difference between a cooper pair box and a transmon qubit?

Tags: experimental-realization, superconducting-quantum-computing

These two kinds of qubits are both classified under "charge qubits", looking for them, I always find the same circuit representation.

[image]

Occasionally, I find one where there's a SQUID instead of the Josephson junction, but I don't think this is the difference.

What is the difference?

Comment: Daniel Sank has a very thorough answer to this here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/185374/why-is-a-transmon-a-charge-qubit/185449